# Trouble hiding a div within a template literal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I've written this bit of jQuery code in Oxygen Builder's JavaScript element to query the job board API and return an array of departments and their jobs. I'm testing to see if the `department[0].jobs.length` returns 0 then hide the #job-list div, otherwise show it and its associated jobs. The code succeeds in querying the API and returning 0 jobs but the remainder of the ternary operator will not hide the div.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.getJSON('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/forwardnetworks/departments', postings => {

    $("#div_block-420-61456").html(`
    <div id="job-list">${postings.departments[0].jobs.length == 0 ? $("#job-list").hide() : $("#job-list").show()}<h3 class="dept">${postings.departments[0].name}</h3>
    ${postings.departments[0].jobs.map(item => `<a href="${item.absolute_url}"><h4 class="job-title">${item.title}</h4></a>
    <p class="job-descrip">${item.location.name}`).join('')}</div> `);
  });
});
```

I generally get a return of [object object]

Comment: `$("#job-list").hide()` and `$("#job-list").show()` each return an object (a jQuery object). Why are you to insert the result of either of these into your `<div id="job-list">` HTML?

Comment: Another question: Why render the `#job-list` at all when there are no jobs and it will just be hidden? It seems like it should not be rendered in that case.

Comment: #job-list is rendered to show a department category that may or may not have an available job. If there are no jobs in the array, then the department and the job should not render to the page. If HR adds a job to a currently empty department, I want it to render to the page.

Comment: This needs refactoring. Even if you do get it to work it's a nightmare from a readability perspective. I would move the logic _outside_ the `html()` function and build the appropriate structure first. Then add it to the DOM. You're doing too much in one bite.

Comment: Protip: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` can just be `jQuery(function($) {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I would add a guard within the `.getJSON` success handler that will return early if there are no jobs to display.

The resulting function would be:

```
const departmentIndex = 0;

$(function ($) {
  $.getJSON('https://boards-api.greenhouse.io/v1/boards/forwardnetworks/departments', postings => {
    if (postings.departments[departmentIndex].jobs.length === 0) { return; }

     $("#div_block-420-61456").html(`
      <div id="job-list">
        <h3 class="dept">${postings.departments[departmentIndex].name}</h3>
        ${postings.departments[departmentIndex].jobs.map(item => `
            <a href="${item.absolute_url}">
                <h4 class="job-title">${item.title}</h4>
            </a>
            <p class="job-descrip">${item.location.name}`
        ).join('')}
      </div>
    `);
  }); 
});
```

Note: I put the index in a variable so that I could easily test with different departments.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/7kv6bd93/) is an example fiddle.